# How should I design the interface to a SQL column generator in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, code-generation, yaml

I'm working on a framework in PHP, part of this frameworks job is to write SQL code to generate new MySQL columns.

What is the most elegant way to pass in a bunch of parameters for a column and then turn that into SQL code? As an example here is some YAML I have, that specifies parameters for creating a varchar column:

```
- type: character
        data-type:
            type: varchar
            length: 255
            decimals: null
            unsigned: null
            zerofill: null
            collate: utf8_unicode_ci
            character-set: utf8
            binary: false
            spatial-type: null
            values: null
        nullify: true
        default: null
        increment: false
        unique: false
        primary: false
        comment: This is a small general text field.
        format: default
        storage: default
```

My design constraints are as follows:

1. The YAML cannot contain any SQL syntax
2. The PHP code must be as concise as possible.

Comment: Im sorry, but that seems like a terrible design. Isn't that a bunch of overhead by containing it in YAML like that?

Comment: you have to consider my use case. This is for a framework for use internally at my company. We want to be able to abstract our common DB column configs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you make a class Column that takes, as a constructor argument, an array that can define the various configuration points you want.  The ones that don't matter in each particular case you just don't define.

Answer (score 0):

Not totaly related but do you know the [Propel](http://propel.phpdb.org/) project ?

They use xml to explain model but [the symfony project](http://www.symfony-project.org) (which use propel as a plugin) use yaml.